# Php download and extract zip timeout page

Tags: php

I have a site developed in php where there is a function to download a zip file, extract him, parse csv inside and insert into database.
    This script is very long because the csv file is large (many MB depends of the content).
    I have already tried with this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_size', '500000M');
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(1);
```

but isn't working, my page in a few minutes go in timeout and block the script.
    The configuration of my server is:

```
max_input_time  -1
max_execution_time  0
memory_limit    512M
safe_mode   Off
```

How can I escape this problem?
    I have see many question about it but any answer is good for me

Comment: Use cron for unzipping, parsing csv and inserting it to database.

Comment: I know but is already a cron and I have tested it because the script isn't working correctly like is stopped for timeout @loncar

Comment: Maybe it's an idea to make an Ajax call that handles it? That way the page is loaded for you browser, and then will an simple ajax call handle the stuff... ( i don't know if this will fix the problem, just my 2 cents tossing in... )